# Disable action method from being called from the address bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, actionmethod

I have a method in my controller that I don't want to be called from the address bar in the browser...

Is there a way to do that? Maybe some kind of annotation, modification in the route configuration? Which are my options?

Comment: How would you prefer this `Action` to be called? `HttpPost` only? Or are you going to call it from within the `Controller`? Could it just be a regular method instead of an `Action`? I think the only way you're going to be able to do this is by using the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are going to use this action only from within your controller or Views then you can use `ChildActionOnly` attribute.

If you want to access it using POST then you can use `[HttpPost]` attribute.

But if you wish to use it using `GET` (i.e. using AJAX call etc) and don't want users to access it using address bar then you can follow this [tutorial](http://helios.ca/2009/05/27/aspnet-mvc-action-filter-ajax-only-attribute/) to make your actions AJAX only.

Or, if you simply want a method that is not an Action at all (i.e. cannot be called using HTTP) then you can either make it `private` or use `[NonAction]` attribute

Comment: I would like to add the ChildActionOnly will only work from Views. If tried to call them from Controller, you will face error as *The action 'Authenticate' is accessible only by a child request.*

Answer (score 8):

Use `NonAction` attribute on the method.

Comment: Can you explain this attribute please ?

Comment: @Zulu, the attribute is to be applied to the controller method which you want to make unavailable as an action: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute.aspx.